# Prove that $d(V/N_1)=d(V/N_2)\Rightarrow d(N_1/N_1\cap N_2)=d(N_2/N_1\cap N_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

**Background**
This problem is taken from the book advanced calculus by h loomis and shlomo sternberg.
I have solved the first two problems:

> 2.9
> A subspace $N$ of a vector space $V$ has *finite codimension* $n$ if the quotient space
> $V/N$ is finite-dimensional, with dimension $n$. Show that a subspace $N$ has finite
> codimension $n$ if and only if $N$ has a complementary subspace $M$ of dimension $n$.
> (Move a basis for $V/N$ back into $V$.) Do *not* assume $V$ to be finite-dimensional.

and

> 2.10
> Show that if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ with finite codimensions,
> then $N=N_1\cap N_2$ has finite codimension and
> $$cod(N)\leq cod(N_1)+cod(N_2)$$
> (consider the mapping $\xi\mapsto \langle\bar{\xi_1},\bar{\xi_2}\rangle$ when $\bar{\xi_i}$ is the coset of $N_i$ containing $\xi$)

**Question**
This is the question I am struggling with:

> 2.11
> In the above exercise, suppose that $cod(N_1)=cod(N_2)$, that is, $d(V/N_1)=d(V/N_2)$.
> Prove that $d(N_1/N)=d(N_2/N)$

**My attempt**
I could only prove it when $V$ is finite-dimensional.
Let $\pi_1\in Hom(N_1, N_1/N)$ and $\pi_2\in Hom(N_2, N_2/N)$ be both the mapping $\xi\mapsto N+\xi$.
$N$ is the null space of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ therefore $\pi_1|_{N_1\setminus N\cup \{0\}}$ and $\pi_2|_{N_2\setminus N\cup \{0\}}$ are isomorphisms.
I can now use a theorem from the book:

> **Theorem 5.3.** Let $T$ be a surjective linear map from the vector space $V$
> to the vector space $W$, and let $N$ be its null space. Then a subspace $M$ is a
> complement of $N$ if and only if the restriction of $T$ to $M$ is an isomorphism
> from $M$ to $W$.

Hence, $N_1=N\oplus (N_1\setminus N \cup \{0\})$ and $N_2=N\oplus (N_2\setminus N \cup \{0\})$.
It is given that $cod(N_1)=cod(N_2)$ therefore I can apply exercise 2.9 and get two subspaces $M_1,M_2$ such that $d(M_1)=d(M_2)$ and $V=N_1\oplus M_1=N_2\oplus M_2$
I can now substiture and get $V=N\oplus (N_1\setminus N \cup \{0\})\oplus M_1$ and $V=N\oplus (N_2\setminus N \cup \{0\})\oplus M_2$
If $V$ is finite dimensional then $$d(N)+d(N_1\setminus N \cup \{0\})+d(M_1)=d(V)=d(N)+d(N_2\setminus N \cup \{0\})+d(M_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow d(N_1\setminus N \cup \{0\})=d(N_2\setminus N \cup \{0\})$$
But $N_1\setminus N \cup \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $N_1/N$ and $N_2\setminus N \cup \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $N_2/N$
Therefore $d(N_1/N)=d(N_2/N)$

(d(V) is the dimension of V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use the concept of quotient-spaces, we can reason like this.
Since $V/N_1\cong (V/N)/(N_1/N)$ and $\operatorname{dim}(V/N)<\infty$ it follows that
$$
\operatorname{dim}(V/N_1)=\operatorname{dim}(V/N)-\operatorname{dim}(N_1/N).
$$
Similarly
$$
\operatorname{dim}(V/N_2)=\operatorname{dim}(V/N)-\operatorname{dim}(N_2/N).
$$
Since by the assumption $\operatorname{dim}(V/N_1)=\operatorname{dim}(V/N_2)$, then
$\operatorname{dim}(N_1/N)=\operatorname{dim}(N_2/N)$.

Note that it does not matter whether $V$ is finite dimensional or not.

---

At the request of the author of the question @Freud,
I give a proof of the formula
$$
\dim(V/N_1)=\dim(V/N)-\dim(N_1/N).
$$
Let's denote for brevity $\overline{V}=V/N$, $\overline{N}_1=N_1/N$.
In view of the formula
$$
V/N_1\cong (V/N)/(N_1/N),
$$
it is sufficient to check that
$$
\dim(\overline{V}/\overline{N}_1)=\dim(\overline{V})-\dim(\overline{N}_1).\hspace{120pt}(1)
$$
We know that $\overline{V}$ has finite dimension
and $\overline{N}_1<\overline{V}$.
Take $\{\bar{e}_1,\ldots,\bar{e}_s\}$ a basis of $\overline{N}_1$
and extend it to
$$
\{\bar{e}_1,\ldots,\bar{e}_s,\bar{e}_{s+1},\ldots,\bar{e}_t\}
$$
a basis of $\overline{V}$.
Then
$$
\{\bar{e}_{s+1}+\overline{N}_1,\ldots,\bar{e}_t+\overline{N}_1\}
$$
form a basis for  $\overline{V}/\overline{N}_1$.

We have
$$
\dim(\overline{N}_1)=s,\
\dim(\overline{V})=s+t,\
\dim(\overline{V}/\overline{N}_1)=t.
$$
Hence our formula $(1)$ follows.

Comment: Why does it follow that $dim(V/N_1)=dim(V/N)-dim(N_1/N) when V is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: In this formula, all vector spaces are finite-dimensional since $V/N$ is finite-dimensional, at the same time, the space $V$ can be infinite dimensional. We are working in $V/N$ space, it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: But why is this formula correct?

Comment: @Freud
We use two formulas:
$$
V/N_1\cong (V/N)/(N_1/N)
$$
and
$$
\dim(V/N_1)=\dim(V/N)-\dim(N_1/N)
$$
which one do you doubt?

I should add that the first formula is always true as long as $N<N_1<V$,
the second formula is true if $\dim(V/N)<\infty$.
The proofs of both formulas are very easy.
Which one do you want to prove?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: @Freud 
 Okay.
I will supplement my answer by including the proof of the second formula.

Comment: Is $\bar{N}=\bar{N_1}$?

Comment: No, it's a typo. I corrected the typos.